# Can I use wildcards for blocking websites in hosts files?

Tags: macos, web, hosts

I'd like to block websites in my hosts file with wildcards. I know that I can block websites by adding them like this

```
0.0.0.0 website.com
::      website.com
```

I'd like to block websites in regex. I heard it's possible to do this with DNS.

Can I do this with the hosts file?

Comment: No, you can't. See e.g. [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384655/how-to-block-hostnames-with-wildcards-or-regex) for alternatives.

Comment: @vssher I've tried adding '127.0.0.1 %s.mycdn.me' (and the 'www' counterpart) to block a site like 'vkvd115.mycdn.me', and it didn't work. Not sure where you got that method from in the first place tbh.